# Please help if this is a decent translation to java of smali code

Tags: java, android, apk, smali, apktool

After googling and trying to understand basics of smali and java, I could come up with this. Please correct me where I have gone wrong.

Original code:

```
.method public Start()Z
    .locals 1

    const-string v0, "ABC"

    invoke-static {v0}, Ljava/lang/System;->loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-direct {p0}, Lcom/battlebot/dday/SplashActivity;->init()V

    const/4 v0, 0x1

    return v0
.end method
```

**Translated to java code:**

```
public Boolean Start() {
         final String v0 = "ABC"; 
         java.lang.System.loadLibrary(v0);
         int v0 = 1;
        }
```

Comment: No, you've left out the call to `com.battlebot.dday.SplashActivity.init()` entirely. Also, I'm not really familiar with Smali, but you've left out the `return` and I believe the `1` will be translated to `return true`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I add the call for com.battlebot.dday.SplashActivity.init()? Please do help.

Comment: How do you add it? You just... add it. How did you add the call to loadLibrary?

Comment: Got it. I must add the same com.battlebot.dday.SplashActivity.init() line just below java.lang.System.loadLibrary(v0);. Is it right, sir?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Also sir, can you please help me modify the "ABC" to any other string so that it is right? Returning v0, can I write return true?

Comment: You can't modify "ABC" to any other string. "ABC" is the name of the library it is loading. Why would you want to change the name of the library it is loading? As for the local variables, yes, you can just write "return true," you don't need to declare a local variable.

Comment: Great sir. Can you also tell me how can I locate the library ABC? I want to edit its contents.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. I've never heard of it before. It seems like you're decompiling an existing app?? It must exist in the APK for that app???

Comment: Yes sir. I've decompiled an apk. I searched the filename but I could not find it in that folder at all. Can you tell me by the code above, the possible location ABC library sir?

Comment: No, I have no idea. If it isn't in the APK, maybe it is some kind of standard Android thing.

Comment: The return value should be a primitive bool, not a Boolean object. Z is for a primitive bool, while Ljava/lang/Boolean; would be for a Boolean object.

Comment: Isn't "true" a  primitive bool in java sir? Please let me know what inste3ad of "true" Imus use. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a decompiler like [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx). Then you would get the decompiled Java code without having to have to deal with smali code.